# Reuse published images

Tags: publications, citations, graphics

I recently wrote an invited book chapter containing figures from different of **my own** papers that were previously published at ACM conferences. Can I reuse them (with citations to the original papers) without permission, or do I need some type of permission from ACM?

Answer (score 3):

You almost certainly need permission. Check the publishing agreement you signed for each of the articles. They're probably all the same, but you might double check the copies you saved if they were in different years.

Comment: Problem is that those PDF copyright statements do not  say anything about reusing parts of that publication. The only thing I found are super-confusing "Author Rights and Publishing Policy" (http://www.acm.org/publications/policies/copyright_policy and http://authors.acm.org/main.html) that mention stuff like "Authors can reuse any portion of their own work in a new work of their own (and no fee is expected) as long as a citation and DOI pointer to the Version of Record in the ACM Digital Library are included".

Comment: So, then you should contact ACM because otherwise you transferred copyright to them.

Comment: @dsfgsho Thank you very much for pointing me to this policy. I'm in a similar situation right now and that helped a lot.